# vue, only bind or use v-model if button in modal is clicked

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having a problem with pre-populating data in a vue-modal on page load, so the modal is rendered and hidden meaning that every row creating a modal already renders a textarea and input that I want to pass to a function on button click.

How can I change this so that I only pass the textarea and hidden input to the props if the save button is clicked?

```
 @foreach($results as $k => $results)
    <tr class="" id="">
        <td>
            <a id="show-row-modal" @click="showModal = {{$k}}; getDetails('{{$results->contentID}}');">{{$results->number}}</a>
            <modal v-if="showModal==={{$k}}" @close="showModal = false">
            <h2 slot="header">{{$results->number}}-{{$results->name}}</h2>

            <div slot="body">
            <textarea style="width:100%; margin: 0 auto;" v-model="resultsContent">{{utf8_encode($results->content)}}</textarea>
            <input type="hidden" value='{$results->contentID}' v-model="existingContentID" />
            <button>save</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach


    <script type="text/x-template" id="row-modal-template">
      <transition name="rowModal">
        <div class="modal-mask">
          <div class="modal-wrapper">
            <div class="modal-container">
            <div class="uk-grid">
              <div class="modal-header uk-form-row uk-width-1-1">
                <slot name="header">
                  default header
                </slot>
              </div>

              <div class="modal-body uk-form-row uk-width-1-1">
                <slot name="body">
                  default body
                </slot>
              </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </transition>
    </script>

     Vue.component('modal',{
    template: '#row-modal-template'
    })

    new Vue({
        el:'#app',
        data: { 
            showModal: false,
            existingCopyID: [''],
            resultsContent: [''],
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using v-model means any change to those inputs will immediately update the piece of state they are bound to. Instead, sounds like you want to use [`refs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) to only retrieve the input values on save click:

```
<textarea style="width:100%; margin: 0 auto;" ref="resultsContent">{{utf8_encode($results->content)}}</textarea>
<input type="hidden" value='{$results->contentID}' ref="existingContentID" />
```

...

```
handleSaveClick() {
  // Grab the value from each input via this.$refs
  console.log(this.$refs.resultsContent.value);
  console.log(this.$refs.existingContentID.value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been fighting with this for a whole day now. Is that a similar issue to what I've done with my checkboxes too? If I select checkboxes on one modal and pop up another then the same checkboxes in that modal are checked